# Building a decision/diagnostic tree

Tags: python, go

I am building a diagnostic tree to debug a distributed system and interested to know if there are any open source tools/libraries in Python/Go

Help in representing a decision/diagnostic tree graphically.
Converting this tree representation to code.
Each node in the tree would run a specific check and based on the outcome (True/False) traverse to the corresponding children node till it reaches the leaf node. So in future user can add a new node anywhere in the visual tree, generated code would incorporate this new node.

I looked into scikit and others but its very specific to Machine learning usecases. A simple binary tree implementation would suffice for my tree.